# Why are my loop cuts not consistent?

Tags: mesh

I am trying to create a loop cut on the walls of a section of a house, however, it doesn't go all the way around. Ngons can't be the problem since I'm sure all faces are quads. However, it might be the orientation of the faces? Could it be the way I have a single-faced wall?

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QEr23shVCqyWr4khNDc9CuGveXZHa71S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the single-faced walls. You have some places where there are 3 planes sharing one edge. The loop tool can't create a loop past these places.  You need to model those walls - the ones where you just have a single plane - like you've modelled most of them, as a U shape.

Comment: I may miss something in your explanation but I'm not sure why you're talking about normals, you could create an edge loop through a series of faces with some flipped normals... Actually, as you pointed out, it's just that it can't create an edge loop through an edge that is shared by 3 or more faces.

Comment: @moonboots OK, just tried what you said and you're right. I was assuming that flipped normals was the reason the tool didn't work on 3+ faces that share an edge, without realising it was just an assumption. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: yes so maybe edit your answer and just keep the real explanation  ;)

Comment: @moonboots OK, done.